# update HISTSIZE from a shell script

Tags: bash, text-processing

I am using grep + sed for updating the `HISTSIZE` variable in the bash profile
using the following:

```bsh
if grep -q "^HISTSIZE=" /etc/profile ; then
  sed -n -i 's/HISTSIZE=.*/HISTSIZE=10000/g' /etc/profile
else
  echo 'HISTSIZE=10000' >> /etc/profile
fi
```

Is it possible to do it in one line for updating any environment variables in bash using sed or awk or any other tool?

Comment: You mention "bashrc" in the title but seem to be using `/etc/profile`. Do you really need to do this for all users? If not, it would be better to use `~/.profile` instead.

Comment: ^^ Added that information to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F= -v k=HISTSIZE -v v=10000 '
  $1==k{$2=v;s=1};1;
  END{OFS="=";if(!s)print k,v}
' /etc/profile > /etc/profile.tmp && mv /etc/profile.tmp /etc/profile
```

---

With GNU awk, you can edit [in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/save-modifications-in-place-with-awk):

```
awk -i inplace  -F= -v k=HISTSIZE -v v=10000 '
   $1==k{$2=v;s=1};1;
 END{OFS="=";if(!s)print k,v}
' /etc/profile
```

---

If you need to change the settings for the current user only, you might want to use `~/.profile` instead of `/etc/profile`.